# Call REST Api from VB.Net WPF application

Tags: java, wpf, vb.net, rest

I have this sample code written in Java that explains how to call a method of a REST Api:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.apac he.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart;

public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String alias = "ABCD";
  String pin = "012345";
  String originFileName = "C:\file.pdf";
  String destinationFilename = "C:\file2.pdf";
  String urlService = "https://serviceUrl";

  Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(MultiPartFeature.class).build();
  FormDataMultiPart form = new FormDataMultiPart();
  form.field("pin", pin);
  form.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("content", new File(originFileName)));

  Response response = client.target(urlService).path("/auto/action/name/" + alias).request(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(Entity.entity(form, form.getMediaType()));
  if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
   InputStream file = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
   File targetFile = new File(destinationFilename);
   try {
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file, targetFile);
    System.out.print("Success");
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.print("Error");
   }
  } else {
   System.out.print("Error:" + response.readEntity(String.class));
  }
 }
}
```

In my application I've converted it to something like this:

```
Dim userAlias As String = "ABCD"
Dim pin As HttpContent = New StringContent("012345")
Dim content As HttpContent = New StreamContent(File.OpenRead(originFileName))

Using client = New HttpClient()
    client.BaseAddress = New Uri(urlService)
    Using formData = New MultipartFormDataContent()
        formData.Add(pinCode, "pin", "pin")
        formData.Add(content, "test", "test")

        Dim response = client.PostAsync("/auto/sign/pades/" + userAlias, formData).Result
        If response.StatusCode = 200 Then
            Return response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(response.ReasonPhrase)
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

As a result I get a 500 Internal Server Error.
I checked the service url and it's correct, so I guess I'm doing something wrong in the MultipartFormDataContent creation.

Comment: Try looking here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141253/attachments-using-rest-webservice-and-vb-net

Comment: If you are interested in code review, don't block on async code with `.Result`. At best it is less efficient than using a synchronous API, at worst it will cause a deadlock. You should await all async calls or, if you can't go async "all the way", you should use a synchronous API like HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the error was caused by a typo in the name of the parameter I was uploading.
The way I created the MultipartFormDataContent was actually correct.
Thanks to @Chillzy for the suggestion that made me rewrite my code finding the typo.